# PHP - CURL - Slowing down after 128MB uploaded

Tags: php, apache, curl, memory, wamp

I am running a script (on windows server 2008 R2 x64, running the last WAMP, using PHP CLI) that upload big files (500-700mb) to a remote host.

Here is the code:

```
function upload_file($file){

//some check to see file exists and get tokens...

//The upload code itself
$post_fields['vfile'] = "@".$file;
$post_fields['upload'] = "1";
$post_fields ['token'] = 'xxxxxx';
if(!empty($user_token))
$post_fields['upload_hash'] = $user_token;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$converter); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
$result=curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close ($ch);

return $result;
}
```

The problem is that, all the time, after 128MB has been uploaded at around 35mb/s, the upload slow down to around 1mb/s until the rest of the file.

My guess was that php memory_limit was the issue, so I tried modifying the php.ini file to memory_limit=-1, then I understood CLI has a different php.ini, I I have then runned php from cmd using -d parameter:

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -d memory_limit=-1 C:\wamp\www\uploader.php

Then I have tried to set

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

When I echo

```
echo ini_get("memory_limit");
```

the result is -1 so I now think php is not the issue, I was wondering if you have any idea to fix this, and keep uploading at 35mb/s? Also, I would like to mention that I am a friend with the remote host, and he assure me there is no upload speed restriction.

Comment: Who are your ISP's, that 35mbps sounds like a cap from your provider - could they also be rate-limiting you on large uploads?

Comment: @MattClark Well, it's a dedicated server from Hetzner, I have a certain amount of TB transfer monthly but as long as I don't reach it, I should have no restriction, and I know I am far to reach it yet, but I like the way you think :) Thank you for the comment anyway